# Send email after crossing 'n' number of messages in dead letter exchange

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp, dead-letter, rabbitmqctl

Is there a proprietary way in rabbitMQ(configurable) to automatically notify our DL after crossing few number of message in dead lettered exchange via some plugins(management plugins).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't anything built in to RabbitMQ to handle this. But if you have any monitoring systems / solutions for your network already, there is likely a plugin for what you are using.

Check out the list of management / monitoring plugins on the site: http://www.rabbitmq.com/how.html#management